# Ansible Roles - not seeing my tasks file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Whenever I run my playbook on my control machine I only see this:

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

So I get the feeling ansible is not finding my task file. Here is my directory structure (it's a git project in Eclipse):

```
ansible
    ansible
        dockerhosts.yml
        hosts
        roles
            dockerhost
                tasks
                    main.yml
```

My dockerhosts.yml:

```
---
- hosts: integration
  roles: [dockerhost]
...
```

My hosts file:

```
[integration]
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.9
```

And my main.yml file:

```
- name: Install Docker CE from added Docker YUM repo
  remote_user: installer
  become: true
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  command: yum -y install docker-ce
```

I don't have any syntax errors clearly as it's running but for some reason it doesn't appear to find my main.yml file. I tried to see what user ansible runs under in case it's a question of file permissions but I haven't found anything.

I am running `ansible-playbook dockerhosts.yml` from the /ansible/ansible directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I set up an ansible/ directory exactly the way you specified in your question, and got a correct response, so it might be something with your local config?

Comment: This leads me to wonder about file permissions. I installed Ansible as root via a YUM package on RHEL 7. It shouldn't have any issues I would think. What permissions do you have on the `ansible/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hosts file but it's not in the `/etc/ansible/hosts` default location. As I showed in my question it's actually at the same level as `dockerhosts.yml` since this is a git project.

I used the -vvvv flag but that didn't tell me much. After running `ansible-playbook -h` I tried the `-i` flag and ran `ansible-playbook dockerhosts.yml -i hosts` and that actually did something.

It gave me SSH connection errors but it did more than just the blank `PLAY RECAP` I got before which to me means it's actually running the tasks now.

Comment: Yes, the blank output in OP is clearly because of missing `-i hosts`, but in this case you should have seen the error `Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts`.

Comment: When I did the yum install ansible installed a default `/etc/ansible/hosts` file on my control machine so I have saw that message.